# Working with nested await in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

I am implementing cache using *MongoDB in-memory* and *MongoDB database* in Nodejs application using mongoose. Here **Nodejs 8.9** is used with async/await support.

---

```
let get_func = async(userId) => {

    let is_cached = await cache_user.findOne({ user_id: userId });

    if(!is_cached){
        console.log("NOT CACHIED");
        let is_dbuser = await db_user.find({});
        console.log(is_dbuser);

    } else {
        console.log("CACHED");
    }

    console.log("LEAVING get_func")
};

get_func(100);
```

And here's the output:

```
NOT CACHIED
[]
LEAVING get_func
```

---

However `db_user` is filled with data and was able to verify using:

```
db_user.find({}, function(err, users) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(users);
});
```

Moreover checked with `let is_error, is_dbuser = await db_user.find({});` if there's a doubt that function returns error and results in that order.

What's the way I should handle this nested await statement. (However it seems function is waiting for second await as expected).

Comment: `let is_error, is_dbuser = await db_user.find({});` wont work. If the promise is rejected, await will behave like throw

Comment: Yeah seems to return promise. Works fine with you other moongose query. Problem only with inner wait.

Comment: I seem to remember that in order to get a fully-fledged promise in Mongoose you need `exec()`. Have you tried: `b_user.find({}).exec()`?

Comment: @Mark_M yeah... tried with `exec()`but same result comes!

Answer (score 1):

do this instead

```
let get_func = async (userId) => {

    let is_cached = await cache_user.findById(userId);

    if(!is_cached){
        console.log("NOT CACHIED");
        let is_dbuser = await db_user.find({});
        console.log(is_dbuser);

    } else {
        console.log("CACHED");
    }

    console.log("LEAVING get_func")
};

get_func(100);
```

please take note that it makes more sense to use findById unless it doesn't satisfy your query requirements and also async may require space before the parenthesis